# How to write a Tornado listener correctly?

Tags: python, listener, tornado

I wanted to write a server background listener to listen to dozens of clients sending commands to this background listener on TCP port 8888. Command format is "http://myip/?c="ClientCommand=A5"

Those clients could be sending commands at the same time or different time. Also, these clients will stay connected and sending few different commands until disconnect by client themselves. All the commands received by the background listener will be written to a MySQL DB.

After few days of study, I found Python + Tornado framework could be a good tool to do this. However, I have tried few days with examples from the web and I still don't know how to program this background listener.

Here is an example I found on a blog and it worked...How do I modify the code below to do the background listener? I know I need to use GET to get parameters from the URL. I have tried get(self.get), but I got error of invalid syntax...
Thanks for your help.

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class IndexHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, Tornado!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application = tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", IndexHandler)
    ])

    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Comment: I suggest you read the docs or you're going to have a bad time: http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/structure.html

"The request handler can access the object representing the current request with self.request"

You probably have to call some method on self.request to get the query parameters. You should be able to find it in the docs.

Comment: Which classes is best for my needs? **tornado.web - RequestHandler and Application classes** or **tornado.websocket - Bidirectional communication to the browser**? Two both look okay for my scenario.  I did read the document, but not much clue. Thanks.